# Bash modify variable value on remote server (with ssh) and use it on my local server

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to perform some operations on my remote server (targeted via ssh), and use the result on my local server.
I know how to perform an operation locally and use it remotely but I've not found any way of doing the reverse operation.

for example:

```
ssh my_remote_server '
   echo "==> ${PWD}"
   ERROR=3
   echo "==> ${ERROR}"
   MYERROR=$((ERROR + 1))     or    'MYERROR'=$((ERROR + 1))
   echo "===> ${MYERROR}"
'
echo "### ${MYERROR}"
```

result obtained:

```
==> /home/toto
==> 3
===> 4
###
```

Expected result:

```
==> /home/toto
==> 3
===> 4
### 4
```

Does anyone know how I could use MYERROR locally?

Comment: Variables are not shared between different computers, or even between processes on the same computer (except for subprocesses getting copies of the parent process's variables when they're forked). To pass variables *in either direction*, you have to 1) get the variable's value on the computer (& in the process) where it exists, and 2) send it over the ssh connection -- as part of the command, or as input to/output from the remote command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of all the other echoing in the script that you send, and just have it echo the new value. Then you can assign the output of `ssh` to a local variable.

```
myerror=$(ssh -T my_remote_server <<'EOF'
error=3
myerror=$((error + 1))
echo "$myerror"
EOF
)
echo "### $myerror"
```

If you want multiple variables, you could have the script echo variable assignments, and then use `eval`

```
eval "$(ssh -T my_remote_server <<'EOF'
echo 'echo "==> ${PWD}"'
error=6
echo 'echo "==> ${error}"'
myerror=$((error + 1))
echo 'echo "===> ${myerror}"'
echo "myerror='$myerror'"
x=2
y=$((x * 3))
echo "y='$y'"
EOF
)"
echo "### $myerror"
echo "### $y"
```

BTW, get out of the habit of using all-uppercase variables. By convention these names are reserved for environment variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Iwill try this way. Unfortunately, I have to share more than one variable. Maybe can I try to store all the variables in an array and return this array. Would it work? What do you think?

Comment: It should work as long as none of the values contain the delimiters in `$IFS`.

Comment: I've added another method using `eval`.

Comment: Yes, it will contain everything that was output.

Comment: awesome it works well thanks. What is important is to have: echo "total=19" on remote side, and echo "$total". the name before = is what has to be displayed. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there a way to keep displaying the logs on the terminal?

Comment: Displaying what logs? You mean things like `==> ${PWD}`? If you use the first method, you can't echo anything other than what you want to put in the variable.

Comment: If you use the second method, you can use `echo 'echo "==> ${PWD}"'` and it will send the `echo` command to the local machine and `eval` will execute it.

Comment: And will it also work for a command such as "compile" for instance where all the compilation logs are displayed?

Comment: You need to prevent any output other than what you want to put in the variables. Redirect other output to files and download them with `scp`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot